# istream_iterator to iterate through bytes in a binary file

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, hex, istream-iterator

Given a file containing the following hex code: 0B 00 00 00 00 00 20 41

I'm trying to populate an **std::vector <std::uint8_t>** and then checking each byte manually.

Here's the code where I create my vector from two std::istream_iterators using the iterator constructor

```
using Bytes   = std::vector<std::uint8_t>;
using ByteItr = std::istream_iterator<std::uint8_t>;

Bytes getBytes()
{
    std::ifstream in;
    in.open("filepath");
    in.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    Bytes bytes;
    ByteItr start(in);
    ByteItr end;
    return Bytes(start, end);
}
```

Here's the unit test I'm trying to pass it through:

```
auto bytes = getBytes();

REQUIRE( bytes.size() == 8 );

CHECK( bytes[0] == 0x0B );
CHECK( bytes[1] == 0x00 );
CHECK( bytes[2] == 0x00 );
CHECK( bytes[3] == 0x00 );
CHECK( bytes[4] == 0x00 );
CHECK( bytes[5] == 0x00 );
CHECK( bytes[6] == 0x20 );
CHECK( bytes[7] == 0x41 );
```

Why is it that in this context, it skips two elements and implicitly converts my vector of std::uint8_t to unsigned chars?

Comment: Could you clarify what do you mean by " it skips two elements and implicitly converts my vector of std::uint8_t to unsigned chars", please ?

Comment: Also once you open your file, you could just `return {ByteItr{in}, ByteItr{}};`, you don't need to `seekg` to the beginning...

Comment: @RiaD What I mean is that it returns only 6 elements where 8 are expected. My list also gets converted to an **std::vector<unsigned char>** when I call the function.

Comment: @Burtonium: `uint8_t` is a typedef for an unsigned 8 bit type. That type is usually, if not always, unsigned char. So it's not converting it from `std::vector<std::uint8_t>` to `std::vector<unsigned char>`. The two types are the same, no conversion required.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`istream_iterator` should not be used for reading binary files. It uses `operator>>`, which is also not suited for reading binary files (unless those files are of a very specific format which most binary files do not fit). You can use [`istreambuf_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istreambuf_iterator) instead. You also want to be sure to open your file in binary mode.

```
in.open("filepath", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
```

Answer (score 12):

Don't use `std::istream_iterator<T>`: that's intended for text formatted input. Most likely it'll skip spaces, for example (you can disable skipping spaces using `std::noskipws`, but that's still the wrong thing to do - use `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>` instead; the type `char` is the character type of the stream).

Also, when processing binary data make sure your stream is opened in binary mode to avoid line end conversions (in case you try that on a platform doing line end conversions). That is, you'd add `std::ios_base::binary` to the open mode.